# Request through proxy Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, proxy

When I run this script on Heroku, I get my project IP instead of proxy. But if I run it on my computer, IP corresponds to proxy.

```py
import requests

proxy = { 
              "http"  : http_proxy, 
              "https" : https_proxy,
            }

res = requests.get(url='http://ip.quotaguard.com/')

print(res.content)
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

You also have to pass the parameter proxies in the request if you want to use proxy

(https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

So your code would become:

```
import requests

proxy = { 
              "http"  : http_proxy, 
              "https" : https_proxy,
            }

res = requests.get(url='http://ip.quotaguard.com/', proxies=proxy)

print(res.content)
```